# Read a string, count occurances WITHOUT USING LOOPS in pYthon

Tags: python

Assume I have a string temp='a computer is a machine'

I want to create a dataframe with 2 columns,'WORD' which contains all the unique words from temp and 'FREQUENCY' which has a total occurances of the word in the string

The dataframe should look like

| WORD | FREQUENCY |
| --- | --- |
| a | 2 |
| computer | 1 |
| is | 1 |
| machine | 1 |

How is this possible in Python WITHOUT USING LOOPS

Comment: There is no [tag:python] in this question.

Comment: Why not use a loop?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects):

```
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd
c = Counter('a computer is a machine'.split(' '))
c
#{'a': 2, 'computer': 1, 'is': 1, 'machine': 1}
pd.DataFrame({"words": c.keys(), "frequency": c.values()})
```

Output:

```
    words  frequency
0         a          2
1  computer          1
2        is          1
3   machine          1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd

temp='a computer is a machine'

c = dict(Counter(temp.split(" ")))

pd.DataFrame([c.keys(), c.values()]).T
```

and this is the result

```
    0           1
0   a           2
1   computer    1
2   is          1
3   machine     1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple approach, but it works.

Take the sentence you want to count the lines from and split it in spaces, having previously put it in lower case and stripped it from spaces on the sides:

```
>>> sentence = "this is an example sentence of a Sentence that has the same sentence in the same Sentence"
>>> words = sentence.lower().strip().split(' ')
>>> words
['this', 'is', 'an', 'example', 'sentence', 'of', 'a', 'sentence', 'that', 'has', 'the',
```

'same', 'sentence', 'in', 'the', 'same', 'sentence']

Then you can count the number of words in the list using numpy, for instance:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> unique, counts = np.unique(words, return_counts=True)
>>> dict(zip(unique, counts))
{'a': 1, 'an': 1, 'example': 1, 'has': 1, 'in': 1, 'is': 1, 'of': 1, 'same': 2, 'se
```

ntence': 4, 'that': 1, 'the': 2, 'this': 1}

Then you can dispose of that information as you wish.

Comment: The point of using lower() and strip() is so that you don't count the same word, in upper and lower case, as two different words.

Answer (score 0):

You could use recursion to 'simulate' a loop:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# Counts the number of occurences of each word in the string s
def count_word_occurences(s):
    word_counts = defaultdict(lambda: 0)

    # Use recursion to 'simulate' a loop
    def add_words(word_list):
        # If the word list isn't empty, there are still words to add
        if word_list:
            # Add the word at the back to the counter
            word_counts[word_list[-1]] += 1
            # Remove the word from the list
            word_list.pop()
            # Add the remaining words
            add_words(word_list)
    
    # Split the string into the words and start counting
    add_words(s.split(' '))
    return word_counts
```